# Angular page on server is blank after compiling and starting server

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7, server-side-rendering

I builded the apllication on angular 7 with server-side rendering on my local enviroinment, on localhost, and everything works perfect. 
My index.html was compiled as should be (on screen). 
But when I tried to get this app on my server on ssh:
-  I started the compilation on angular app by command "npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr", so server.ts was started 
- then I started the server.js to start ssh server

Now I have just blank page, and index.html looks only with . It shoudn't looks like that after compiling angular app.
here is the structure of files on ssh server: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ailDCELJTLM_vut4mC6Bc2CWeRAmpYq/view?usp=sharing

here is the screen from localhost:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E8DnLvvAt02uBhkuxIsREZKduuiPIeFW

and from beta-server ssh:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-CNrhaT9XgRo03igahEd_UwXpDAqRklH

As you can see, the root was not compiled and I don't know what i do wrong

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');
var timeout = require('connect-timeout'); //express v4

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

//TEST - timeout
app.use(timeout(600000));

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`ROHUB Angular2 app is running on localhost:${port}`));
```

server.ts

```
mport 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ng-universal-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.git"
  },
  "contributors": [],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "lint": "ng lint ng-universal-demo",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod  --output-hashing=none && ng run ng-universal-demo:server:production",
    "build:prerender": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server && npm run generate:prerender",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "compile:server": "tsc -p server.tsconfig.json",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "generate:prerender": "cd dist && node prerender",
    "serve:prerender": "cd dist/browser && http-server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server"
  },
  "pre-commit": [],
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
[...]
```

I exprected the same look on browser both on browse and on browse console, but page from server is blank.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?